# javascript not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, canvas

Im trying to use this Gauges - https://canvas-gauges.com

I create javascript with this gauges and it works fine in chrome and Firefox, but in doesn't work in IE 11

There is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
<head>
    <title>Gauges as Components</title>



<script src="http:////cdn.rawgit.com/Mikhus/canvas-gauges/gh-pages/download/latest/all/gauge.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center" >CPU Dashboard</h1>

<canvas id="canvas-id" >
</canvas>
<script>

var gauge = new RadialGauge({
    renderTo: 'canvas-id',
    animationRule: "linear",
    animationDuration: 1500,
    needleCircleInner: false,
    needleCircleOuter: true,
    needleCircleSize: 7,
    needleWidth: 2,
    needleType: "arrow",
    borders: false,
    borderShadowWidth: 0,
    colorPlate: "#fff",
    highlights: [
        {
            "from": 160000,
            "to": 200000,
            "color": "rgba(255,216, 0, 1)"
        },
        {
            "from": 200000,
            "to": 268000,
            "color": "rgba(255, 50, 50, .75)"
        }
    ],
    strokeTicks: true,
    minorTicks: 2,
    majorTicks: [
        "0",
        " ",
        " ",
        " ",
        " ",
        " ",
        " ",
        " ",
        " ",
        " ",
        " ",
        "268000"
    ],
    valueDec: 0,
    valueInt: 5,
    maxValue: 268000,
    minValue: 0,
    value:150000,
    units: "mhz",
    title:"CPU UTIL",
    height: 300,
    width: 300
}).draw();


</script>



</body>
</html>
```

I'm new in javascript. What I do wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works for me.  What does not work for you?  Look in the error console?

Comment: I found this error - DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337 and SCRIPT5009: 'RadialGauge' is undefined

Comment: Use Local Js file . cdn.rawgit.com not loading in IE. But Local gauge.js working.

Comment: Very intresting. When I use local js file it works in IE. But i Need open it on web server from oter computers with IE. How I can load this js in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just use local js file and now it works in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had the issue when my ES6 code does not work at IE11.

I had used [IFEE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

I convert my code via the [Babel recompiler](https://babeljs.io/repl) and that helped me out to get everything to work just like in Chrome.